# Bash script variable with comma seperated values is not comma seperated when appended to a different file

Tags: bash, script

I have a bash script that validates table entries. The final output value is $out which is inserted into an SQL INSERT statement which is then appended to /tmp/crew.txt.
While $out is clearly comma separated there are no commas between the values in the resulting INSERT statement in /tmp/crew.txt. Why is this the case and how can it be fixed so I do have comma separated values in /tmp/crew.txt?

```
#!/bin/bash

out=290,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20.5,NULL

echo "${out:1}"

290,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20.5,NULL


echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES ("${out:1}");" >> /tmp/crew.txt
```

```
vi /tmp/crew.txt

INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES ( 290 '02:20:00' '02:40:00' 20 NULL);
```

Thus the result in /tmp/crew.txt should be:

```
INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES ( 290,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20,NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hypothesis: your `IFS` variable contains `,`. The script does not change the `IFS`, so the non-default value must have been in the environment.

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1564884/432690) noticed you have unquoted `${out:1}` in a line that looks like this:

```
echo "foo"${out:1}"bar"
```

Unquoted variable [undergoes word splitting and filename generation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Word splitting is by `IFS`. The unquoted `${out:1}` is split to multiple words, `echo` gets multiple arguments and prints them separated by single spaces (because this is what `echo` does, no matter the `IFS`).

If you used `printf` [as advised](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618), it would be easier to tell if the variable is quoted:

```
printf 'INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES (%s);\n' "${out:1}"
```

And if you didn't double-quote the variable, `printf` would get multiple arguments from `${out:1}` and it would generate multiple lines. Then it should be quite obvious some splitting occurs. Using `echo` that concatenates its arguments obfuscated this fact to some degree.

---

Separate issues:

- The desired output suggests you don't want `"${out:1}"` but `" $out"` with a leading space.
- To include single-quotes in the variable you should make sure the shell doesn't remove them. Escape them (credits to the [already mentioned answer](https://superuser.com/a/1564884/432690)) or double-quote them:

  ```
  out="290,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20.5,NULL"
  ```

Comment: "I'm sure a bash expert will be along soon who can explain the why for you" I was right :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Why is this the case and how can it be fixed

Removing the echoed output and blank lines from your script gives the following cleaned up script:

```
#!/bin/bash
out=290,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20.5,NULL
echo "${out:1}"
echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES ("${out:1}");" >> /tmp/crew.txt
```

Running that script though [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) produces the following error:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 4:
echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES ("${out:1}");" >> /tmp/crew.txt
>>                                                                                      ^-- SC2027: The surrounding quotes actually unquote this. Remove or escape them.

$
```

Removing the quotes as suggested fixes that error, so now we have:

```
#!/bin/bash
out=290,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20.5,NULL
echo "${out:1}"
echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES (${out:1});" >> /tmp/crew.txt
```

However running this still doesn't give the right answer as `echo "${out:1}"` shows that the single quotes `'` are not stored in `out`, and they will need to be escaped:

```
$ test.sh
90,02:20:00,02:40:00,20.5,NULL
$
```

Fixing this gives:

```
#!/bin/bash
out=290,\'02:20:00\',\'02:40:00\',20.5,NULL
echo "${out:1}"
echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES (${out:1});" >> test.txt
```

Note I've changed the output filename to `test.txt`

Testing:

```
$ test.sh
90,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20.5,NULL
$ cat test.txt
INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES (90,'02:20:00','02:40:00',20.5,NULL);
$
```

So the final fixed version of your script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
out=290,\'02:20:00\',\'02:40:00\',20.5,NULL
echo "${out:1}"
echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES (${out:1});" >> >> /tmp/crew.txt
```

Here endeth the lesson on debugging your broken script.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is to echo the following INSERT statement:

```
echo "INSERT INTO tip_run (date_linkid, start_time, finish_time, weight, note) VALUES (${out:1});" >> /tmp/crew.txt
```

No escaping necessary. Not sure about the why however.

Comment: I'm sure a bash expert will be along soon who can explain the why for you :)